# How to disable pagination using display tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

In my jsp page i use displaytag for search results. Pagination works fine but i want to disable the pagination (i mean to display all the records in the same page itself).

I found nothing under displayTag.properties file  commneted the whole file and also mentioned pagesize="1" in the jsp page .

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.stockDetails" pagesize="1"

    <display:column property="buyerssellersdiff" title="Buyers Count" sortable="true"
        headerClass="sortable" />
</display:table>
```

But its still showng 4 pages .

How can i display all results under one page ??

Comment: Have you tried with `length` property in table tag to set size of all records?

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked . you saved my time , thanks once again .